# Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I want to annotate some text on last facet of the plot with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
p <- p + annotate("text", label = "Test", size = 4, x = 15, y = 5)
print(p)
```

[image]

But this code annotates the text on every facet. How can I get the annotated text on only one facet?

Comment: I believe this is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/486), so I suspect you'll have to resort to the tried and true method of constructing a data frame with the text, and a column for the faceting variable.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Function `annotate()` adds the same label to all panels in a plot with facets. If the intention is to add different annotations to each panel, or annotations to only some panels, a geom_ has to be used instead of `annotate()`. To use a geom, such as `geom_text()` we need to assemble a data frame containing the text of the labels in one column and columns for the variables to be mapped to other aesthetics, as well as the variable(s) used for faceting.

Typically you'd do something like this:

```
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text",
                       cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text")
```

It should work without specifying the factor variable completely, but will probably throw some warnings:

[image]

Comment: I seem to run into some blurry labels when I try to use geom_text() on my faceted plot. It's the same problem discussed here (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/evsbeBT48M4), and was resolved by using annotate("text",...). Does anyone else get blurry labels with geom_text()?

Comment: @Margaret Usually, that's because you've mistakenly told ggplot to plot a copy of each label for every row in your original data frame (the one with the points, lines, etc.). Note that that I pass a separate data frame to `geom_text` with only one row.

Comment: Ok I got that-Thanks. What if you wanted to put 3 different labels on your faceted plot? I tried a dataframe with as many rows as I had facets, and unique labels in each row. Maybe I should start this as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm wondering if I can also do this using `annotate()`...?

Comment: How can I do this if I have two levels in 'facet_wrap'?

Comment: @user3420448 The same, you just have to specify values for each faceting variable.

Comment: If one wants to actually use the value in `lab` column, one could do `geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label = lab))` instead.

Comment: For me this creates the character "a" in the legend of the plot. Does this happen to anybody else?

Comment: This link might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337653/remove-a-from-legend-when-using-aesthetics-and-geom-text

Comment: To get rid of the character "a" in the legend, just add `show.legend = FALSE` to the geom, e.g.: `geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label = lab), show.legend=FALSE)` @stephanmg

Answer (score 193):

Function `annotate()` adds the same label to all panels in a plot with facets. If the intention is to add different annotations to each panel, or annotations to only some panels, a *geometry* has to be used instead of `annotate()`. To use a geometry, such as `geom_text()` we need to assemble a data frame containing the text of the labels in one column and columns for the variables to be mapped to other aesthetics, as well as the variable(s) used for faceting. This answer exemplifies this for both `facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()`.

Here's the plot without text annotations:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))
p
```

[image: plot without text annotations]

Let's create an additional data frame to hold the text annotations:

```
dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c("4 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "8 cylinders"),
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8)
)
p + geom_text(
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = label),
  hjust   = -0.1,
  vjust   = -1
)
```

[image: plot with text annotations at edges]

Alternatively, we can manually specify the position of each label:

```
dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c("4 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "8 cylinders"),
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8),
  x     = c(20, 27.5, 25),
  y     = c(4, 4, 4.5)
)

p + geom_text(
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = label)
)
```

[image: plot with manually positioned text labels]

We can also label plots across two facets:

```
dat_text <- data.frame(
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 8),
  am    = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
)
dat_text$label <- sprintf(
  "%s, %s cylinders",
  ifelse(dat_text$am == 0, "automatic", "manual"),
  dat_text$cyl
)
p +
  facet_grid(am ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(
    size    = 5,
    data    = dat_text,
    mapping = aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label),
    hjust   = 1.05,
    vjust   = 1.5
  )
```

[image: facet by two variables]

Notes:

- You can use `-Inf` and `Inf` to position text at the edges of a panel.
- You can use `hjust` and `vjust` to adjust the text justification.
- The text label data frame `dat_text` should have a column that works with your `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`.

Comment: This answer is superior to the accepted answer (obviously a 5-year difference between the two) for how clearly it steps through each step. Also greater clarity and explanations.

Comment: If you want to add text to multiple rows, make sure that your `colnames()` in the text `data.frame` match those of the data you are about to plot.

Comment: When I try doing this for a single one of my facets, the annotation shows up but the actual points are gone (or obscured?).

Comment: Ben G, you might consider making a new post to share your code and figure.

Answer (score 66):

If anyone is looking for an easy way to label facets for reports or publications, the [`egg`](https://rdrr.io/cran/egg/src/R/tag_facet.r) ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/)) package has pretty nifty `tag_facet()` & `tag_facet_outside()` functions.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ am) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)

# install.packages('egg', dependencies = TRUE)
library(egg)
```

#### Tag inside

**Default**

```r
tag_facet(p)
```

[image]

**Note:** if you want to keep the strip text and background, try adding [`strip.text` and `strip.background`](https://rdrr.io/cran/egg/src/R/tag_facet.r) back in `theme` or remove `theme(strip.text = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())` from the original `tag_facet()` function.

```r
tag_facet <- function(p, open = "(", close = ")", tag_pool = letters, x = -Inf, y = Inf, 
                      hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5, fontface = 2, family = "", ...) {

  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  lay <- gb$layout$layout
  tags <- cbind(lay, label = paste0(open, tag_pool[lay$PANEL], close), x = x, y = y)
  p + geom_text(data = tags, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label"), ..., hjust = hjust, 
                vjust = vjust, fontface = fontface, family = family, inherit.aes = FALSE) 
}
```

**Align top right & use Roman numerals**

```r
tag_facet(p, x = Inf, y = Inf, 
          hjust = 1.5,
          tag_pool = as.roman(1:nlevels(factor(mtcars$am))))
```

[image]

**Align bottom left & use capital letters**

```r
tag_facet(p, 
          x = -Inf, y = -Inf, 
          vjust = -1,
          open = "", close = ")",
          tag_pool = LETTERS)
```

[image]

**Define your own tags**

```r
my_tag <- c("i) 4 cylinders", "ii) 6 cyls")
tag_facet(p, 
          x = -Inf, y = -Inf, 
          vjust = -1, hjust = -0.25,
          open = "", close = "",
          fontface = 4,
          size = 5,
          family = "serif",
          tag_pool = my_tag)
```

[image]

#### Tag outside

```r
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cyl ~ am, switch = 'y') +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside')

tag_facet_outside(p2)
```

[image]

**Edit**: adding another alternative using the [stickylabeller](https://github.com/rensa/stickylabeller) package

```r
- `.n` numbers the facets numerically: `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`...
- `.l` numbers the facets using lowercase letters: `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`...
- `.L` numbers the facets using uppercase letters: `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`...
- `.r` numbers the facets using lowercase Roman numerals: `"i"`, `"ii"`, `"iii"`...
- `.R` numbers the facets using uppercase Roman numerals: `"I"`, `"II"`, `"III"`...

# devtools::install_github("rensa/stickylabeller")
library(stickylabeller)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ am, 
             labeller = label_glue('({.l}) am = {am}')) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

<sup>Created by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Source says "Adds a dummy text layer to a ggplot to label facets and sets facet strips to blank. " Ergo, if you have custom facet label strips you don't want to lose, edit the script for `tag_facet` by nixing `strip.text = element_blank()`

Comment: @CrunchyTopping This was actually hat I was looking for, but it does not seem to work for me: ```Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: strip.text```

Comment: To answer my issues above...this post nicely explains how to keep the strips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56064130/3609450

Comment: This is an amazing answer @Tung ! Super helpful!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ecg :)

Comment: @Tung This is a good answer to a different question, so it would deserve its own question rather than remain rather hidden here.

Comment: @Tung, how can I add the minimum point of ggplot in each grid(facet)?

Answer (score 24):

I think for the answer above lab="Text" is useless, the code below is also ok.

```
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,
                       cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text" )
```

However if you want to label differently in different sub-graphs, it will be ok in this way:

```
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = c(14,15),wt = c(4,5),lab=c("text1","text2"),
                       cyl = factor(c(6,8),levels = c("4","6","8")))
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,aes(label =lab) )
```

Comment: You should explain in depth what your solution offers in comparision to the already given and accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful for labeling different sub-graphs.

Comment: For some reason, when I do this, it adds (empty) facets for factors cyl=2 and cyl=3.

Answer (score 16):

Expanding slightly on joran's excellent answer, to clarify how the label  dataframe works.

You can think of "mpg" and "wt" as the x and y coordinates, respectively (I find it easier to keep track of the original variable names than renaming them, as in Kamil's also-excellent answer).  You need one row per label, and the "cyl" column shows which facet each row is associated with.

```
ann_text<-data.frame(mpg=c(25,15),wt=c(3,5),cyl=c(6,8),label=c("Label 1","Label 2"))

ann_text
>  mpg wt cyl  label
>  25  3   6   Label 1
>  15  5   8   Label 2

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ factor(cyl))
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label=ann_text$label)
```

[image: plot with labels]

Answer (score 3):

I did not know about the `egg` package,
so here is a plain `ggplot2` package solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
Data1=data.frame(A=runif(20, min = 0, max = 100), B=runif(20, min = 0, max = 250), C=runif(20, min = 0, max = 300))
Data2=data.frame(A=runif(20, min = -10, max = 50), B=runif(20, min = -5, max = 150), C=runif(20, min = 5, max = 200))
```

```
bind_cols(
Data1 %>% gather("Vars","Data_1"),
Data2 %>% gather("Vars","Data_2")
) %>% select(-Vars1) -> Data_combined
```

```
Data_combined %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  summarise(r=cor(Data_1,Data_2),
            r2=r^2,
            p=(pt(abs(r),nrow(.)-2)-pt(-abs(r),nrow(.)-2))) %>%
  mutate(rlabel=paste("r:",format(r,digits=3)),
         plabel=paste("p:",format(p,digits=3))) ->
  label_df
```

```
label_df %<>% mutate(x=60,y=190)
```

```
Data_combined %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Data_1,y=Data_2,color=Vars)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=label_df,aes(x=x,y=y,label=rlabel),inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data=label_df,aes(x=x,y=y-10,label=plabel),inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
    facet_wrap(~ Vars)
```

Comment: What does this solution bring to the previous ones?