# ggplot2 facet_wrap plotting points, segments, text in every facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the same issue that has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508277/adding-annotation-segment-arrow-in-only-certain-facet-ggplot). However, the solutions there do not appear to be working.

I have example data here:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggrepel")

# order of the chromosomes
chrom_order <- c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4", "chr5", 
    "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", "chr12", 
    "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", "chr17", "chr18", "chr19", 
    "chr20", "chr21", "chr22", "chrX", "chrY", "chrM")

# data frame of chromosome sizes
chrom_sizes <- structure(list(chrom = structure(c(25L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", 
"chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", 
"chr12", "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", "chr17", "chr18", 
"chr19", "chr20", "chr21", "chr22", "chrX", "chrY", "chrM"), class = "factor"), 
    size = c(16571L, 249250621L, 243199373L, 198022430L, 191154276L, 
    180915260L, 171115067L, 159138663L, 146364022L, 141213431L, 
    135534747L, 135006516L, 133851895L, 115169878L, 107349540L, 
    102531392L, 90354753L, 81195210L, 78077248L, 59128983L, 63025520L, 
    48129895L, 51304566L, 155270560L, 59373566L)), .Names = c("chrom", 
"size"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")

# regions to label 
sample_cns <- structure(list(gene = c("AFF1", "ANKRD24", "ARID1A", "CDH23", 
"CDH23-AS1", "CHD5", "CTC-554D6.1", "DCC", "DOT1L", "FLT4"), 
    chromosome = structure(c(4L, 19L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 18L, 
    19L, 5L), .Label = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4", "chr5", 
    "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", "chr12", 
    "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", "chr17", "chr18", "chr19", 
    "chr20", "chr21", "chr22", "chrX", "chrY", "chrM"), class = "factor"), 
    start = c(87869685L, 4183350L, 27022894L, 73199588L, 73269838L, 
    6166339L, 112162804L, 49867157L, 2164183L, 180030191L), end = c(88056853L, 
    4224502L, 27107247L, 73575035L, 73270969L, 6240083L, 112179823L, 
    51057023L, 2229791L, 180076545L), log2 = c(-1.01818, -0.517649, 
    -1.14236, -0.527636, -0.527636, -1.14236, -0.438652, -0.741936, 
    -0.517649, -0.438652), depth = c(466, 155.508, 304.046, 720.821, 
    1096.83, 253.5, 871.9, 626.033, 160.42, 567.457), weight = c(17.8883, 
    17.0764, 23.296, 52.0485, 1.77117, 25.5399, 22.9053, 19.3831, 
    26.4509, 19.0353), cn = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), probes = c(587L, 462L, 1023L, 922L, 922L, 1023L, 
    753L, 465L, 462L, 753L)), .Names = c("gene", "chromosome", 
"start", "end", "log2", "depth", "weight", "cn", "probes"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

# base plot
p <- ggplot(data = chrom_sizes, aes(x = chrom, y = size)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey90") + coord_flip() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + facet_wrap( ~ chrom, scales = "free_y")

print(p)
```

Which produces the desired base plot shown here:

[image]

However, I next want to annotate the plot with the entries in the `sample_cns` dataframe. But when I try to add them, every value gets placed in every plot:

```
# places labels and lines on every facet
p + geom_segment(data = sample_cns, aes(x = chromosome, xend = chromosome, y = start, yend = end, colour = cn), size=13) + 
    geom_text_repel(data = sample_cns, aes(x = chromosome, y = start, label = gene))
```

[image]

As per the referrenced questions, I tried passing a single-entry dataframe to add the annotations one at a time. However, this still results in the data being plotted in every facet. The same happens when I try to re-create the dataframe from scratch and pass it instead, and it happens with text, line segments, and points being passed:

```
# first row only; still adds to every facet
df <- sample_cns[1, ]
p + geom_segment(data = df, aes(x = chromosome, xend = chromosome, y = start, yend = end, colour = cn), size=13) + 
    geom_text_repel(data = df, aes(x = chromosome, y = start, label = gene))


# make new df from scratch
df <- data.frame(gene = "AFF1", chromosome = factor("chr4", levels = chrom_order), start = 87869685, end = 88056853, cn = 1)
p + geom_segment(data = df, aes(x = chromosome, xend = chromosome, y = start, yend = end, colour = cn), size=13) + 
    geom_text_repel(data = df, aes(x = chromosome, y = start, label = gene))

p + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = chromosome, y = start, colour = cn), size=13)
```

[image]
[image]

Any ideas? What am I missing? Why does this same technique work in those other code samples, but not here?

Also I am using R version 3.2.3, and `ggplot2` version 2.2.1

Comment: You are faceting by a column called `chrom`, `facet_wrap( ~ chrom)`. Your data frame for the labels, `cns`, does not have a column called `chrom`, so it is part of every facet. If you want labels to appear only on certain facets, and a column called `chrom` to `cns` that show which facet each label should be in.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that fixed it.

Comment: @Gregor if you post that as an Answer, I will accept it

Comment: One other note - I'd encourage you to make *minimal* examples in the future. You'll get quicker help with more approachable questions. You did a nice job sharing reproducible data, but if you had subset your data/plots down to just 2 or 3 facets the problem is still illustrated, but it makes your question look so much shorter that it will get help more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell `ggplot` which facet each labels go in. This means the data frame containing the labels needs to have the column(s) you facet on.

You are faceting by a column called `chrom`, `facet_wrap( ~ chrom)`. Your data frame for the labels, `cns`, does not have a column called `chrom`. Add a column called `chrom` to `cns` that show which facet each label should be in.