# ggplot: Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 with Facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a faceted scatterplot with `ggplot` but I'm struggling to add the regression line equation to each of the facets. The simple case where there is no faceting has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) but this method won't extend to a faceted plot.

Any ideas how to accomplish this in a clean fashion?

Comment: Better to give some reproducible data and provide what you have tried...

Comment: The suggested duplicate points to a link that I have already provided in my question. One of the comments on that link, which wasn't answered, also asks the same question of how to add the equation on a faceted plot. The trick seems to be to pass a `vector`/`data.frame` for the labels. I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is an example starting from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)


lm_eqn = function(df){
    m = lm(y ~ x, df);
    eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
         list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
              b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2), 
             r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
    as.character(as.expression(eq));                 
}
```

Create two groups on which you want to facet

```
df$group <- c(rep(1:2,50))
```

Create the equation labels for the two groups

```
eq <- ddply(df,.(group),lm_eqn)
```

And plot

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
            geom_point()
p1 = p + geom_text(data=eq,aes(x = 25, y = 300,label=V1), parse = TRUE, inherit.aes=FALSE) + facet_grid(group~.)
p1
```

[image]

Comment: @agstudy, I'm trying to use `annotate` instead of `geom_text` but I'm unable to pass the `eq` dataframe or the column `eq$V1` to it. Could you help me with that please?

Comment: @JT85, irrespective of the above comment, your answer works perfectly well for my current problem which is why I've accepted it already. I'd still like to use `annotate` instead though.

Comment: No problem. However I don't think `annotate` works like that with `facet_grid`. agstudy's approach is just completely different. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @JT85 This is a **great work around**, but it leaves one major flaw, IMHO.  The line is plotted ***using different code*** than the actual equation.  For a simple linear least squares, big deal.  But what if I, for instance, wanted to use the nice `loess` polynomial fit.  I would have to recreate `loess`, then presume I have set all my parameters / assumptions correctly.  Isn't there a simple `show.eqn` flag or something like that?  If not, why?  That seems so fundamental to a regression fit!  (BTW, I know it's not your code.  Just asking the general crowd here...)

Comment: It appears that `, inherit.aes=FALSE` is not necessary to get the same output, but perhaps this was inserted for an older version of R or ggplot. I have R 3.2.3 and ggplot  2.1.0

Comment: As of R 3.5 at least, `format()` does not discard anymore the `names` attribute of `coef(m)[1]` and the `lm_eqn(df)` function returns `"italic(y) == c(\`(Intercept)\` = \"-0.83\")…` instead of somehing like `"italic(y) == \"-0.83\" …`. This can be corrected by discarding name attributes with `as.numeric(coef(m)[1])`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(ggplot2); library(gridExtra)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)

grid.newpage()
vpa_ <- viewport(width = 1, height = 1)
print(p, vp = vpa_)
grid.text("y ~ mx + b", x=0.3, y=0.8)
grid.text("y ~ mx + b", x=0.5, y=0.8)
grid.text("y ~ mx + b", x=0.8, y=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need the equation more importantly.

Comment: I think you can pass a vector/list/etc. to `annotate` , like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2

Comment: You're probably right. In the link you've put, the answered isn't passing a vector to `annotate` though. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that doesn't work does it. Editing answer above with a gridextra solution that I use often

Answer (score 4):

Using `gridExtra` you can arrange yours plots like this.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

library(ggplot2)
iris$x = iris$Sepal.Length 
iris$y = iris$Sepal.Width
xx <- range(iris$x)
yy <- range(iris$y)

ll <- by(iris,iris$Species,function(df){
  x.eq <- max(xx)-mean(xx)/2
  y.eq <- max(yy)*0.95
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    annotate(x=x.eq, y =y.eq ,  geom='text',
              label = lm_eqn(df), size=5,parse=TRUE) +
    xlim(xx[1],xx[2])+ylim(yy[1],yy[2])
})

library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange,ll)
```

Comment: Thanks. `grid.arrange` seems to work more like `facet_wrap` than `facet_grid`. Is that right? If so, I would like to get the `facet_grid` sort of solution to work.