# Stop parsing out zeros after decimals in ggplot2's annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to annotate a location on a ggplot2 plot with a line that contains both a (real) greek letter and a number rounded to 2 decimal places. My problem arises because I want to display the decimal places even if they are both zero. Unfortunately, the `parse = T` setting in `annotate` converts the string `"1.00"` into `"1"`. Here's a specific example:

```
alpha_num <- "1.00"
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1,y=1,label=paste0("alpha == ", alpha_num)))
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x,y,label=label), parse = TRUE, size = 30)
```

The code above produces the following plot:[image: annotate is parsing out my zeros]

How do I get `alpha_num` displayed in its entirety?

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108062/how-to-write-after-decimal-zero-in-ggplot-geom-text) but the answer below is much better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with the use of `deparse`.

So your code looks like this

```
alpha_num <- "1.00"
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1,y=1,label=paste0("alpha == ", alpha_num)))
# Use deparse in label
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x,y,label=paste0("alpha == ", deparse(alpha_num))), parse = TRUE, size = 30)
p
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: So much better than [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108062/how-to-write-after-decimal-zero-in-ggplot-geom-text)!

Comment: what if the object to deparse is a vector? you will not only get your zeros back, but also the full vector with all its elements.