# multiple columns plot with correlation value in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression

Hi I have a dataframe `df` as below.
I would like to make a facet plot that shows relation between columns `A & B`, `A & C`, `A & D` , `B & C` and `C & D` and overlay a regression line and person's correlation coefficient value.
I am trying to make a facet plot to show relation between each of these column could not figure out exactly how.
Any help would be appreciated. This question is unique in SO as there are not any ans for plot among columns.

```
df<- read.table(text =c("A  B   C   D
0.451   0.333   0.034   0.173
0.491   0.27    0.033   0.207
0.389   0.249   0.084   0.271
0.425   0.819   0.077   0.281
0.457   0.429   0.053   0.386
0.436   0.524   0.049   0.249
0.423   0.27    0.093   0.279
0.463   0.315   0.019   0.204
"), header = T)

df
pl<-ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=A,y=B,size=10)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=A,y=C,size=10)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=A,y=C,size=10)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=A,y=D,size=10)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black")
pl
```

Comment: Try `GGally::ggpairs(df)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot: Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 with Facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699858/ggplot-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-with-facet)