# Add text to individual facets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how I put different text in individual facets. I want to add the text ***inside*** the plot using `annotate` or `geom_text()` I know there are duplicated posts in this, but I don't manage to get it correct. Here is my data:

```
Experiment         FC           Pairing
Meister et al. -2.74236520      yes
Meister et al. -0.7436354       no
Meister et al. -2.74236520      yes
Meister et al. -0.73536354      no
daub et al.    -0.64246768      yes
daub et al.    -0.6663321       no
daub et al.    -0.64246768      yes
daub et al.    -0.6663321       no
hans et al.    -2.32230716      yes
hans et al.    -0.49423279      no
hans et al.    -2.32723716      yes
hans et al.    -0.4944279       no

ggplot(combined_pos1,aes(Pairing,FC,fill=as.factor(Pairing))) + 
      geom_boxplot(fill = "grey90") +  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3)) + 
      facet_grid(~Experiment)
```

Comment: Did you try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the text in the strip labels for each facet (where it currently says "Meister et al.", "Daub et al.", etc.), or are you saying you want to place text annotations inside the plot area of each facet?

Comment: Suggestion: Post your data in a reproducible form using output of `dput`

Comment: @eipi10 Yes I want to add the text as annotation inside the plot. One unique text for each facet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the annotations for each facet (here as an example for Meister and Hans):

```
combined_pos1$annotations = c("Text for Meister",rep("",10),"Text for hans")
```

include geom_text:

```
g = ggplot(combined_pos1,aes(Pairing,FC,fill=as.factor(Pairing))) + geom_boxplot(fill = "grey90") +  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3)) + facet_grid(~Experiment)
g = g + geom_text(aes(x=2.5,y=2.5,label=annotations))
g
```

This yields the following:
[image]

Comment: @BioMan This is a clear duplicate, the answer was given to you in the comments but you didn't read.

Comment: @baptiste Sorry if I missed something in the comments.

Comment: If you want to add text to multiple rows, make sure that your `colnames()` in the text `data.frame` match those of the data you are about to plot.