# ggplot facets: show annotated text in selected facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, annotate, geom-text

I want to create a 2 by 2 faceted plot with a vertical line shared by the four facets. However, because the facets on top have the same date information as the facets at the bottom, I only want to have the `vline` annotated twice: in this case in the two facets at the bottom.

I looked a.o. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2), which does not work for me. (In addition I have my doubts whether this is still valid code, today.) I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508277/adding-annotation-segment-arrow-in-only-certain-facet-ggplot?noredirect=1&lq=1). I also looked up how to influence the font size in `geom_text`: according to the help pages this is `size`. In the case below it doesn't work out well.

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

my_df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
                      "Date AM_PM First_Second Systolic Diastolic Pulse 
                    01/12/2017 AM 1 134 83 68 
                    01/12/2017 PM 1 129 84 76
                    02/12/2017 AM 1 144 88 56
                    02/12/2017 AM 2 148 93 65
                    02/12/2017 PM 1 131 85 59
                    02/12/2017 PM 2 129 83 58
                    03/12/2017 AM 1 153 90 62
                    03/12/2017 AM 2 143 92 59
                    03/12/2017 PM 1 139 89 56
                    03/12/2017 PM 2 141 86 56
                    04/12/2017 AM 1 140 87 58
                    04/12/2017 AM 2 135 85 55
                    04/12/2017 PM 1 140 89 67
                    04/12/2017 PM 2 128 88 69
                    05/12/2017 AM 1 134 99 67
                    05/12/2017 AM 2 128 90 63
                    05/12/2017 PM 1 136 88 63
                    05/12/2017 PM 2 123 83 61
                    ")

# setting the classes right
my_df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(my_df$Date), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
my_df$First_Second <- as.factor(my_df$First_Second)

# to tidy format
my_df2 <- gather(data = my_df, key = Measure, value = Value, 
                  -c(Date, AM_PM, First_Second), factor_key = TRUE)

# Measures in 1 facet, facets split over AM_PM and First_Second
## add anntotations column for geom_text
my_df2$Annotations <- rep("", 54)
my_df2$Annotations[c(4,6)] <- "Start"

p2 <- ggplot(data = my_df2) +
  ggtitle("Blood Pressure and Pulse as a function of AM/PM,\n Repetition, and date") +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value, col= Measure, group = Measure), size = 1.)  +
  geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Value, col= Measure, group = Measure), size= 1.5) +
  facet_grid(First_Second ~ AM_PM) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.Date("2017/12/02")), linetype = "dashed", 
             colour = "darkgray") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90)) 

p2
```

yields this graph:
[image]

This is the basic plot from which I start. Now we try to annotate it.

```
p2 + annotate(geom="text", x = as.Date("2017/12/02"), y= 110, label="start", size= 3)
```

yielding this plot:

[image]

This plot has the problem that the annotation occurs 4 times, while we only want it in the bottom parts of the graph.

Now we use `geom_text` which will use the "Annotations" column in our dataframe, in line with [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371307/add-text-to-individual-facets-in-ggplot?noredirect=1&lq=1). Be carefull, the column added to the dataframe must be present when you create "p2", the first time (that is why we added the column supra)

```
p2 + geom_text(aes(x=as.Date("2017/12/02"), y=100, label = Annotations, size = .6))
```

yielding this plot:

[image]

Yes, we succeeded in getting the annotation only in the bottom two parts of the graph. But the font is too big ( ... and ugly) and when we try to correct it with `size`, two things are interesting: (1) the font size is not changed (although you would expect that from the help pages) and (2) a legend is added.

I have been clicking around a lot and have been unable to solve this after hours and hours. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11889625/707145)?

Comment: `size` (and all other arguments that don't involve mapping a data column to an aesthetic) should be outside of `aes()`. That will get rid of the legend and result in size actually changing the size of the text to the desired value.

Comment: @eipi10 This works. Thank you! Should I remove the question? It looks rather ridiculous now.

Comment: If your problem is solved and it was just a matter of moving `size` outside of `aes` then you can delete it or I could mark it as a duplicate. Whichever you prefer.

Comment: @eipi10  I spent hours on it, the problem is rather well stated, the solution might be of help to other non-experts. I prefer not to delete it.