# Annotating text on individual facets in ggplot2 #2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, facet

I'm also having some trouble with annotating text to individual facets in ggplot2 (w/ reference to related post: [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)).

**Data frame:**

```
str(cfit_2)
'data.frame':   186 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Participant: Factor w/ 31 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Condition  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Active control group",..: 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Time       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Pretest","Posttest": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CFIT       : num  10 13 17 11 19 15 19 11 15 16 ...
 $ Version    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Total CFIT","CFIT version 1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

**Code:**

```
p<-ggplot(cfit_2,aes(Time,CFIT,fill=Condition))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:20)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","lightgrey"))+
  geom_violin()+
  theme_classic()+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1, 20),xlim=c(1, 2))+
  theme(axis.line=element_blank())+
  facet_grid(.~Version)+ylab("CFIT raw score")+

  geom_segment(x=.3925,xend=.3925,y=1,yend=20)+
  geom_segment(x=1,xend=2,y=.015,yend=.015)+

 stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",position=position_dodge(w=.9))+
 stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot,geom="errorbar",position=position_dodge(w=.9),width=0)+

   geom_segment(data=data.segm_1,aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
   geom_segment(data=data.segm_2,aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
   geom_segment(data=data.segm_3,aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
   geom_segment(data=data.segm_1_2,aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
   geom_segment(data=data.segm_2_2,aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
   geom_segment(data=data.segm_3_2,aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[Violin plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qFb7.png)

What I want to do is to add "NS" or "*" next to every segment. Using the following data frame:

```
ann_text<-data.frame(Time=c("Pretest","Posttest","Pretest","Posttest","Pretest","Posttest"),CFIT=c(8,7,3,2,2,3),
       lab=c("NS","*","NS","*","NS","*"),
       Version=factor(c("Total CFIT","Total CFIT","CFIT version 1","CFIT version 1","CFIT version 2","CFIT version 2"),
                levels=c("Total CFIT","CFIT version 1","CFIT version 2")))
```

ann_text:

```
Time CFIT lab        Version
1  Pretest    8  NS     Total CFIT
2 Posttest    7   *     Total CFIT
3  Pretest    3  NS CFIT version 1
4 Posttest    2   * CFIT version 1
5  Pretest    2  NS CFIT version 2
6 Posttest    3   * CFIT version 2
```

... I get the following result from p+geom_text(data=ann_text,aes(label=lab)):

```
**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Condition' not found**
```

---

Moving aes(fill=Condition) to geom_violin() gives the following plot:

[Violin plot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WN2m.png)

Comment: Any variable used in the global setting of aes is passed down to all other layers. So in this case, it is probably better to move fill=Condition to geom_violin()

Comment: Thanks @Heroka! That works fine, except now I'm having trouble with the stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot,geom="errorbar",position=position_dodge(w=.9),width=0; above).

Comment: Hm. I didn't see all of your code due to the formatting (and I can't do a quick tinker myself as your q is not reproducible), but you could use override.aes. As an aside, you could consider combining data to create all your segments, creates cleaner and easier code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to tell `geom_text` to not use `Condition` for the fill, by setting it to `NULL`. This way, you can keep `fill` in the `ggplot` call and have it applied to all other `geoms`, without the need to specify it each time.

## Create data (since you didn't supply any)

```
cfit_2 <- data.frame(
  Time = c('Pretest', 'Posttest'),
  Condition = rep(c('Active control group', 'Training group'), each = 2),
  Version = rep(c('Total CFIT', 'CFIT version 1', 'CFIT version 2'), each = 40),
  CFIT = rnorm(120, 10, 3)
)
```

## Use your plotting code

```
p<-ggplot(cfit_2,aes(Time,CFIT,fill=Condition))+
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:20)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","lightgrey"))+
  geom_violin()+
  theme_classic()+
  #coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1, 20),xlim=c(1, 2))+
  theme(axis.line=element_blank())+
  facet_grid(.~Version)+ylab("CFIT raw score")+

  geom_segment(x=.3925,xend=.3925,y=1,yend=20)+
  geom_segment(x=1,xend=2,y=.015,yend=.015)+

  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",position=position_dodge(w=.9))+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot,geom="errorbar",position=position_dodge(w=.9),width=0)
```

(Note that I commented out two lines about the axes, since they were giving me troubles. I also removed the annotated lines, since you didn't supply data for those.)

## Add the text

First create the coordinates where you want the asterisks and "NS"es.

```
ann_text<-read.table(text="
Time CFIT lab        Version
Pretest    15  NS     'Total CFIT'
Posttest    7   *     'Total CFIT'
Pretest    3  NS 'CFIT version 1'
Posttest    2   * 'CFIT version 1'
Pretest    2  NS 'CFIT version 2'
Posttest    3   * 'CFIT version 2'
",header=T)
```

Then annotate.

```
p + geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label = lab, fill = NULL))
```

## Result

[image]

Of course, the text doesn't look that nice (it's at the wrong y level), but that is because my data is different.

Comment: Thank you @Axeman, that works great with my admittedly messy code.

Comment: Yeah, it's usually better to provide a minimal example that still has the same problem (i.e. remove all the extra bits like theme calls etc.). Also, supplied (fake) data is always nice!

Comment: Yes, lots of unnecessary information. I'm sorry about that. Obviously I'm very new to this (basically no experience with coding, R or stack). Nice of you to point it out. (Btw I don't even know how to supply data.)