# Add text to plot with facetted bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, facet, errorbar

My question is related to this question. I want "2014" in the 4-year facet. I tried to repeat but my code doesn't give what I want.

[Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

This is my data

```
structure(list(Rot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2-year", 
"3-year", "4-year"), class = "factor"), Rot.Herb = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("A4-conv", "A4-low", 
"C2-conv", "C2-low", "C3-conv", "C3-low", "C4-conv", "C4-low", 
"O3-conv", "O3-low", "O4-conv", "O4-low", "S2-conv", "S2-low", 
"S3-conv", "S3-low", "S4-conv", "S4-low"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Diversity", 
    "Evenness"), class = "factor"), N = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), value = c(0.78537789925, 0.613408315, 
    1.305194686, 0.79519430975, 0.4481728555, 0.30608817425, 
    1.20978861475, 0.8580643725, 0.92387324875, 0.630166121, 
    0.945954185, 0.561172324, 1.43952456275, 0.8616864655, 1.23679146725, 
    0.831737624, 1.033474108, 0.80689293925, 0.9910142125, 0.79342098075, 
    1.175512223, 0.6293940245, 0.981614832, 0.62342189825, 1.351710013, 
    0.805075937, 1.6598348325, 0.7983622545, 1.01606920875, 0.5751418795, 
    1.0500365255, 0.56408326225, 1.07162937725, 0.6756859865, 
    0.45699816625, 0.44444147325), sd = c(0.354077266902404, 
    0.208934910331856, 0.169501822767995, 0.0774319459391732, 
    0.737366460962239, 0.40697977697835, 0.494107033311986, 0.11906912863268, 
    0.491492768082854, 0.34236657107712, 0.219739438843007, 0.205905593411204, 
    0.319301583035043, 0.0696484379979274, 0.0563293598951725, 
    0.0978700910274188, 0.446850757364563, 0.175073468716825, 
    0.426859848850874, 0.180469101499932, 0.526842123835502, 
    0.200470277385505, 0.574885944755375, 0.27189545397305, 0.39621771945215, 
    0.150798258847229, 0.275863362594154, 0.111178397407429, 
    0.254811233135664, 0.158920851982914, 0.198698241334475, 
    0.0730606635175717, 0.717706309307313, 0.453776579066358, 
    0.574276936403411, 0.513758415496589), se = c(0.177038633451202, 
    0.104467455165928, 0.0847509113839974, 0.0387159729695866, 
    0.368683230481119, 0.203489888489175, 0.247053516655993, 
    0.0595345643163399, 0.245746384041427, 0.17118328553856, 
    0.109869719421504, 0.102952796705602, 0.159650791517521, 
    0.0348242189989637, 0.0281646799475863, 0.0489350455137094, 
    0.223425378682282, 0.0875367343584126, 0.213429924425437, 
    0.090234550749966, 0.263421061917751, 0.100235138692753, 
    0.287442972377688, 0.135947726986525, 0.198108859726075, 
    0.0753991294236146, 0.137931681297077, 0.0555891987037145, 
    0.127405616567832, 0.0794604259914568, 0.0993491206672376, 
    0.0365303317587859, 0.358853154653656, 0.226888289533179, 
    0.287138468201705, 0.256879207748294), ci = c(0.563415944919255, 
    0.332462066715199, 0.26971522480343, 0.123211505132525, 1.1733145846647, 
    0.647595643784969, 0.786234551289211, 0.189465554245211, 
    0.782074671929471, 0.544781614588516, 0.349654482635521, 
    0.327641747494367, 0.508080071600555, 0.110826207087643, 
    0.089632581638694, 0.155733154793995, 0.71103927089404, 0.278580956835532, 
    0.679229274424713, 0.287166612643164, 0.838323385234058, 
    0.318992946792351, 0.914771825423139, 0.432646341459985, 
    0.630470808679215, 0.23995368085579, 0.438960169525453, 0.176909640028318, 
    0.40546153371869, 0.252878539112781, 0.316173242000635, 0.116255819336536, 
    1.14203089616693, 0.722059798737006, 0.91380275723334, 0.817504285602766
    )), .Names = c("Rot", "Rot.Herb", "variable", "N", "value", 
"sd", "se", "ci"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the code to graph

```
p <- ggplot(Shannon.long2, aes(x=Rot.Herb, y=value, fill=factor(variable)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(~Rot, scales = "free_x", space="free_x")+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.text=element_text(size=20),legend.position="top")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), size=0.5, width=.25,position=position_dodge(.9))+
  xlab("\nTreatment") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=24,face="bold", vjust=4), axis.text.x = element_text(size=20,angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ylab("Shannon's H' and E'") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=24,face="bold", vjust=2), axis.text.y = element_text(size=20, color="black"))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20), strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

produced graph (please don't mind the "2014" on the y-axis).
[image]

New code to annotate 2014, with help from eipi10

```html
 ann_text <- data.frame(x = "S4-conv",y = 1.75,lab = "2014", Rot.Herb=NA, 
value=NA, variable=NA, 
N=NA, sd=NA, se=NA, ci=NA, 
Rot = factor("4-year",levels = c("2-year","3-year","4-year")))
```

I got an error saying `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` after I run `p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "2014")`. Please see what have been wrong with my code and data format. Thanks.

Comment: Add `ann_text$Rot.Herb=NA` to your annotation data frame. Even though you're not using that column in `geom_text`, ggplot expects it to be there if that column is used for an aesthetic in the main call to ggplot.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Did you mean `ann_text <- data.frame(x = "S4-conv",y = 1.75,lab = "2014",
                       Rot = factor("4-year",levels = c("2-year","3-year","4-year")), ann_text$Rot.Herb=NA)? I did that and got new error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found`

Comment: That's because you also use the column `value` in your initial ggplot call. So you need to add `ann_text$value=NA` to your new data frame as well. Every column that's used in your initial call to ggplot also needs to be in any data frames you introduce into the plot later.

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't been able to make it yet. This is my full edited code with all the column names in `Shannon.long2`: `ann_text <- data.frame(x = "S4-conv",y = 1.75,lab = "2014", Rot.Herb=NA, value=NA, variable=NA, N=NA, sd=NA, se=NA, ci=NA,
                       Rot = factor("4-year",levels = c("2-year","3-year","4-year")))` . I got new error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` but I did transform `Rot` to factor though.

Comment: I've reopened the question, pending resolution of whether there's something else going on besides the issue I've already raised. For now, please take the code in your comment and add it as an update to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that when you include `value=NA` in `ann_text` it gets interpreted as logical (rather than numeric, which is its mode in `Shannon.long2`), causing the error because ggplot expects a numeric variable rather than a categorical one. Set `value=NA_real_` (in addition to `NA`, R has class-specific missing value constants; see `?NA` for more info) in `ann_text` to ensure `value` is interpreted as numeric and resolve the error. Or set `value` to any number, e.g., `value=0`.

In the example below, I've removed all of the `theme` and `lab` statements to shorten the code down to the essentials:

```
p = ggplot(Shannon.long2, aes(x=Rot.Herb, y=value, fill=factor(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), size=0.5, width=.25,position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(~Rot, scales = "free_x", space="free_x")

ann_text <- data.frame(x = "S4-conv", y = 1.75, lab = "2014", Rot.Herb=NA, 
                       value=NA_real_, variable=NA)

p + geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label=lab, x, y))
```

Note that you also need to feed `x` and `y` values to `geom_text` to provide the label location.

Another option would be to just use the same x and y variable names as in your original data frame, since ggplot already knows these names and has scaled the graph based on them. Now the only missing column we need to add is `variable`:

```
ann_text <- data.frame(Rot.Herb = "S4-conv", value = 1.75, lab = "2014", variable=NA)

p + geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label=lab, Rot.Herb, value))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time investigating the problem. I really appreciate.

Comment: I ended up using this set of code
`ann_text <- data.frame(x= "C2-low", y = 1.75,lab = "2014", 
                       variable=NA_real_, Rot.Herb=NA, value=0, N=0, sd=0, se=0, ci=0,
                       Rot = factor("2-year",levels = c("2-year","3-year","4-year")))

p + geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label=lab, x, y), size=8)`