# adding geom_text to 2D facet_grid ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot facet_grid where I want to add different text labels to each individual plot.

[image]

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) for mapping to a one-dimensional facet_grid

```
library(ggplot2)

ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = c(14,15),wt = c(4,5),lab=c("text1","text2"),
                       cyl = factor(c(6,8),levels = c("4","6","8")))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(gear ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(data = ann_text,aes(label =lab) )
```

But this produces the following:
[image]

How does the matching to `ann_text` work inside the `geom_text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify both `cyl` **and** `gear` in your `ann_text` `data.frame`, as these are the variables you are using for facetting:

```
library(ggplot2)

ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = c(14,15),
                       wt = c(4,5),
                       lab=c("text1","text2"),
                       cyl = c(6,8),
                       gear = 3)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(gear ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(label = lab))
```

[image]

From there, it's pretty easy to get what you're looking for:

```
ann_text2 <- data.frame(mpg = 14,
                       wt = 4,
                       lab = paste0('text', 1:9),
                       cyl = rep(c(4, 6, 8), 3),
                       gear = rep(c(3:5), each = 3))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(gear ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(data = ann_text2, aes(label = lab))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, of note is that the x and y values from the ggplot(aes()) command, i.e. mpg and wt, MUST be present in the ann_text2 data_frame. This stumped me