# I want to annotate some text on faceted plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to annotate some text on the faceted plots with the following code:

```
ggplot(All.Leads, aes(Air_Volume, Proximal_Bowing, color = Model)) + 
facet_wrap(facets = ~Model, nrow = 3) + 
geom_point(size = 1.5) + 
geom_smooth(method = lm, se =  FALSE) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgoldenrod1", "grey55", "dodgerblue1")) + 
labs(title = "Influence of Intracranial Air Volume on Maximum Proximal Lead 
Bowing", xlab = "Intracranial Air Volume (mm^3)", ylab = "Maximum Proximal 
Lead Bowing (mm)") +
geom_text(x = 3500, y = 3.5, label = "Medtronic: r = 0.81", color = 
"dodgerblue1") + 
geom_text(x = 3500, y = 4.1, label = "Boston Scientific: r = 0.57", color = 
"grey45") + 
geom_text(x = 3500, y = 4.7, label = "Abbott/SJM: r = 0.44", color = 
"darkgoldenrod1") + 
theme_classic()
```

I want to include the "Medtronic: r = 0.81" geom_text on the bottom facet, "Boston Scientific: r = 0.57" geom_text in the middle facet, and "Abbott/SJM: r = 0.44" geom_text on the top facet.  Any help would be much appreciated!

See ggplot image here:  http://rpubs.com/Gopher16/393175

Comment: See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) to see if they help.  If so, this may be a duplicate.