# Annotation text on individual facet in ggplot2 # 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, facet-grid

This is a follow-up question on the post [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) which already helped me a lot, but it considers facets with a single variable.

I would like to add text to a single panel of a ggplot graph with **2 faceting variables** (facet_grid).

The code before adding text:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
geom_point() +
facet_grid(gear ~ cyl)
```

results in the following plot:

[Plot without geom_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4O9i.png)

When I add geom_text, the annotation is added correctly, but 2 additional and meaningless panels without data are added:

```
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text", 
cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")), gear = factor(4, levels = c("3",  "4", "5")))

p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text")
```

[Plot with geom_text, mind 2 additional panels without data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQpQ5.png)

How can I get rid of these 2 additional panels without data?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: It works for me if you create ann_text a little differently: `ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text", cyl = c(8), gear = c(4))`. I was a bit confused by your choice of `factor` because gear and cyl are not factors in `mtcars`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ulrike how about we treat `gear` and `cyl` as factors in the `facet_grid()` call? This way you'll not have to change the data at all. The reason I'm treating `gear` and `cyl` as factors because, if you look at the structure of `mtcars` dataset, you will notice `gear` and `cyl` contain discrete values. This means we can coerce them to `factor`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text", 
                       cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")), 
                       gear = factor(4, levels = c("3",  "4", "5")))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(factor(gear) ~ factor(cyl))+
  geom_text(aes(mpg,wt, label=lab),
            data = ann_text)
```

[image]