# How to annotate text on individual facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

This question is a follow-up to: [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

I was trying out the code provided in the accepted answer and got something that was strangely different than the result provided. Granted the post is older and I'm using R 3.5.3 and ggplot2 3.1.0, but what I'm getting doesn't seem to make sense.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

#below is how the original post created a dataframe for the text annotation
#this will produce an extra facet in the plot for reasons I don't know
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text",cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))

p+geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text")
```

This is the code from the accepted answer in the linked question.  For me it produces the following graph with an extra facet (i.e, an addition categorical variable of 3 seems to have been added to cyl)

[image: https://github.com/RamenZzz/hello-world/blob/master/Rplot09b.jpeg?raw=true]

```
#below is an alternative version that produces the correct plot, that is,
#without any extra facets.
ann_text_alternate <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text",cyl = 8)

p+geom_text(data = ann_text_alternate,label = "Text")
```

This gives me the correct graph:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamenZzz/hello-world/master/Rplot09a.jpeg]

Anybody have any explanations?

Comment: Run `str(ann_text)` The last row of the output is `$ cyl: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 3`. So the level `"8"` is code as the number `3`. Since you facet by `cyl` you have one more value. Another solution is `facet_grid(. ~ factor(cyl))`.

Comment: @Rui post an answer, maybe. These problems with facets are pretty much common; I once fell into the lap of one, not long ago.

Comment: @M-M Done. As a matter of fact, I had considered posting as an answer, since sometimes it happens to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on is a factors issue.
First, you facet by `cyl`, a column in dataset `mtcars`. This is an object of class `"numeric"` taking 3 different values.

```
unique(mtcars$cyl)
#[1] 6 4 8
```

Then, you create a new dataset, the dataframe `ann_text`. But you define `cyl` as an object of class `"factor"`. And what is in this column can be seen with `str`.

```
str(ann_text)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ mpg: num 15
# $ wt : num 5
# $ lab: Factor w/ 1 level "Text": 1
# $ cyl: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 3
```

R codes factors as integers starting at `1`, level `"8"` is the level number `3`.
So when you combine both datasets, there are **4** values for `cyl`, the original numbers `4`, `6` and `8` plus the new **number**, `3`. Hence the extra facet.

This is also the reason why the solution works, in dataframe `ann_text_alternate` column `cyl` is a numeric variable taking one of the already existing values.

Another way of making it work would be to coerce `cyl` to factor when faceting. Note that

```
levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))
#[1] "4" "6" "8"
```

And the new dataframe `ann_text` no longer has a 4th level. Start plotting the graph as in the question

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ factor(cyl))
```

and add the text.

```
p + geom_text(data = ann_text, label = "Text")
```