# Adding labels to each individual plot with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am attempting to add labels (capital letters) to each plot in the following `facet_grid`:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl)
```

This outputs:
[image]

What I would like to have is this:
[image]
The major issues I am having is 1) My Y axis is scaled freely, so inputting specific coordinates for each isn't working. 2) I am not sure what keywords I should be searching here, I am sure there is a way to do this in `facet_grid` but I am unable to find it.

Comment: I can give you a solution but without using facet_grid, and using instead ggpubr and creating each plot panel. I don't know if that would be useful for you. If it is, I will post it.

Comment: The `tag_facet` function from the `egg` package should do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/52217208/786542

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for and works nicely. Thank you!

Comment: @AMB: not a problem. Feel free to post an answer to help future readers

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Fixing the position of label as the upper-left corner of each plot panel:

```
 p + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl)+ annotate('text', label = LETTERS[1:12], x=min(mpg$displ), y=max(mpg$cty))
```

You can replace label =c('aaa','bb','fff'....), anything you like, but has to be the same number of your facet plots.

You can also fine-tune the position of the label proportional to both axis by using:

```
x=mean(mpg$displ)*0.6, y=max(mpg$cty)*0.97
```