# How to combine italic and non-italic components of a `geom_text` call. Add `geom_text` labels to a series of `facet_grid` scatter plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, facet-grid, geom-text

I'd like to include a text label that indicates the correlation coefficient on a series of `facet_wrap`ped scatterplots (eg: "r = -0.52").

So my scatterplots look something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = hp)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") + 
  facet_grid(~ factor(cyl))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I've then tried to create three separate correlation coefficients, after grouping, and I'd like the label to show up on the diagram, but it's not quite right. I'd like it to say something like: "r = -0.52"

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(correlation = cor(y = mpg, x = hp, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl correlation
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     4      -0.524
#> 2     6      -0.127
#> 3     8      -0.284
df <- left_join(df, df2, by = "cyl")

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = hp)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  geom_text(x = 200, y = 30, label = expression(paste(italic(r), " = ", df$correlation))) +
  facet_grid(~ factor(cyl))
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/11889625/786542

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
  geom_text(x = 200, y = 30, 
            label = paste0("italic(r) == ", df$correlation), parse = TRUE)
```

To display a rounded correlation:

```
  geom_text(x = 200, y = 30, 
            label = paste0("italic(r) == ", round(df$correlation,2)), parse = TRUE)
```

Comment: That's it, nice. I think a clearer title for this question would be "How to combine italic and non-italic components of a `geom_text` call".

Comment: great maybe just add the rounding as edit for completeness: `  geom_text(x = 200, y = 30, label = paste0("italic(r) == ", round(df$correlation,2)), parse = TRUE)`

Comment: Good call, @heds1. I didn't realise. I'll try to edit the title now.

Comment: one other question: when I'm calling `round(df$correlation, 2)`, that's actually a whole column of the same correlation coefficients repeated. Is there a way where I could take the average of the column? Obviously, it has the same answer in this case, but just for my future knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `geom_text` after the `facet_grid` for R to know where to put it:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = hp)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  facet_grid(~ factor(cyl)) +
geom_text(x = 200, y = 30, 
          label = paste0("italic(r) == ", round(df$correlation,2)), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a complete answer as OP is using `expression`

Comment: Do you have any hints as to how I can make the "r =" in italics? I was trying to use `expression` but I am open to any solution

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent did answer that part in a nice way :).