# ggplot: how annotate different strings in different positions in different boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, I'm plotting data from two different dataframes, called respectively **ASD** and **TD**, using ggplot boxplot.

Each dataframe reports 3 variables:

- a (numeric)
- b (numeric)
- condition (categorial, can be "ASD" or "TD")

[image]
[image]

I successfully created two graph; in each graph I plotted the same variable, respectively **a** and **b**, from the two datafames, side by side, so to compare them. I then added to each graph a given string, namely "Jonh" and "Jerry". Both strings are printed at y=35, using *annotate*.

**problem**: how can I change the y position for each string? In the example, I would like to print the string "Jerry" (in the graph for variable **b**) at y=10

[image]

Here follows the code I used:

```
#clearing variable and console
cat("\014")
rm(list = ls())
message("Graphic test for boxplot")

#libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# creation of dataframe ASD, with numeric variables 'a' and 'b',
# and a categorial variable 'condition' with fixed value 'ASD' 
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(26:35)
ASD <- cbind(a,b)
ASD.df <-as.data.frame(ASD)
ASD.df$condition <- "ASD"

# creation of dataframe TD, with numeric variables 'a' and 'b',
# and a categorial variable 'condition' with fixed value 'TD' 
a <- c(6:15)
b <- c(24:33)
TD <- cbind(a,b)
TD.df <-as.data.frame(TD)
TD.df$condition <- "TD"


# union of ASD and TD in a single dataframe C
C.df <- rbind(ASD.df,TD.df)

# reshaping of C for ggplot, using variable 'condition'
C.df_melted <- melt(C.df, id.var = "condition")


#strings I want to visualise on each graph
myStr <- c("John", "Jerry")

#do I want a fixed y lim?
FIXED_Y_LIM <- TRUE

myBox <- ggplot(data=C.df_melted, aes(x=condition, y=value, fill=variable))+
geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) +
facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free") + 
annotate(geom="text", x=1.5, y=35, label= myStr)

# it forces y scale in this range
if(FIXED_Y_LIM==TRUE)
{
  myBox <- myBox + ylim(0, 40)  
}

myBox
```

I tried to solve modyfing the annotate line from

```
annotate(geom="text", x=1.5, y=35, label= myStr)
```

to

```
annotate(geom="text", x=1.5, y=c(35, 10), label= myStr)
```

but I obtain this error that I don't understand:

*Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label*

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: `myStr` is not in `C.df_melted`, hence the error. Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to the number of vectors in the `C.df_melted` `data.frame`.

An *alternative* is to use `labeller` on `facet_wrap()`:

```
ggplot(data=C.df_melted, aes(x=condition, y=value, fill=variable)) +
geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) +
facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free", labeller=as_labeller(setNames(myStr, c("a", "b"))))
```

Or to answer your question more directly with the aid of [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) and `geom_text()`:

```
ggplot(data=C.df_melted, aes(x=condition, y=value, fill=variable)) +
geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) +
facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free") +
geom_text(data=data.frame(label=myStr, y=c(35, 10), variable=c("a", "b")), mapping=aes(x=1.5, y=y, label=label))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2), we add the positions and each label to `C.df_melted`. Instead of `annotate` we use `geom_text`:

```
C.df_melted$x <- rep(1.5, nrow(C.df_melted))
C.df_melted$y <- c(rep(35, nrow(C.df_melted)/2), rep(10, nrow(C.df_melted)/2))
C.df_melted$myStr <- c(rep("John", nrow(C.df_melted)/2), rep("Jerry", nrow(C.df_melted)/2))

myBox <- ggplot(data=C.df_melted, aes(x=condition, y=value, fill=variable))+
geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) +
facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free") + 
geom_text(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = myStr))
```