# How do I plot text on different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have read quite a bit and have tried following multiple examples from this post below but I am still getting an error.
[Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

Maybe I am making a simple mistake that I cannot see ?

Here is one iteration of my code:

```
ann_text <- data.frame(Gender = factor(c("Female","Male"),levels=c("Female","Male")) ,lab = c(captionF,captionM))
        ##
        g<-ggplot(dat.czm.annot.otu,aes_string(x=condition2,y="counts"))+geom_boxplot(alpha=0.8,outlier.size = -1)+
          facet_wrap(~Gender)+
          #  geom_point(aes(fill=Diet),size = 3, shape = 21,position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.02,jitter.height = 0))+
          geom_point(aes(fill=Gender),size = 3, shape = 21,position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.02,jitter.height = 0))+
          guides(fill=FALSE)+
          #annotate("text",x=c(1.5,1.5),y=c(0.7*ymax,0.8*ymax),label=c(captionM,captionF))+
          ggtitle(otu_name_clean)+
          ylab("proportion")+
          labs(subtitle=paste(subset,"subset"),caption=caption)+
          theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold"))+
          theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
                axis.title=element_text(size=14)) + 
          theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14),
                legend.title=element_text(size=14)) +
          theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14))
        g+geom_text(data = ann_text,label=ann_text$lab)
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Time' not found

Time is `condition2`, that is the x variable for the boxplots, specified in `aes_string`.

Any help is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

now it works when I specify the x and y position in the aes mapping.

g+geom_text(data = ann_text,aes(x=Inf,y=ymax,label=lab))