# How to label only one facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid

Im trying to label only one facet in my plot...

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
p <- p + annotate("text", label = "Test", size = 4, x = 15, y = 5)
print(p)
```

[image: example]

when I try the suggested fix on another post [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) , it does not work....

```
ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text",
                   cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text")
```

[image: example 2]

any sugestions?

Comment: just don't run the `p + annotate` line

Comment: The line: "cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))" should be the factor that has been faceted. However, when I apply it to my data i get an error message saying the object does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way that worked for me in the past was to create a new data frame, with the the facet variable containing only one value, as shown below.

```
library(tidyverse)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
p <- p + geom_text(data = data.frame(x = 15, y = 5, cyl = 4, label = "Test"), 
                   aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), size = 4)
print(p)
```

This will generate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct version based on the suggested fix provided above should be as follows:

`ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 15,wt = 5,lab = "Text", cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8"))) p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = ann_text$lab)`

It should be `label=ann_text$lab`, instead of `label="Text`.