# Trying to label only one facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid

I am trying to label only one of my facets, but i am receiving an error message when I try to apply a solution.

```
structure(list(pot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 137L, 
138L, 139L, 140L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Dinninup", 
"Riverina", "Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35), form = c(3.66, 
2.02, 1.59, 1.67, 2.12, 2.46, 1.79, 2.09, 2.03, 2.13, 1.83, 2.34, 
2.66, 2.2, 1.79, 1.97, 2.17, 2.44, 1.49, 2.19, 2.92, 2.43, 1.58, 
2.07, 2.48, 2.49, 1.69, 2.1, 2.38, 2.52, 2.41, 2.46, 2.22, 2.07, 
1.97, 2.3, 2.48, 3.16, 1.76, 2.38, 2.81, 2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 3.18, 
2.57, 2.9, 3, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 3.06, 3.01, 3.01, 2.77, 
2.95, 2.36, 2.91, 2.38, 3.33, 3.19, 3.17, 3.16, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 
3.71, 3.11, 2.7, 2.92, 1.93, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 3.34, 2.75, 
2.52, 1.88, 1.19, 0.57, 0.64, 0.66, 1.13, 1.28, 0.85, 0.96, 1.34, 
2.14, 0.63, 1.27, 1.13, 0.64, 1.21, 1.95, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 
1.06, 1.07, 1.05, 0.8, 1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.98, 1.27, 1.01, 
1, 1.16, 0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 1.03, 1.13, 0.79, 0.6, 3.88, 2.79, 
2.73, 2.77, 3.54, 2.05, 1.51, 1.88, 3.86, 3.13, 1.97, 3.46, 3.98, 
3.6, 2.12, 2.86, 2.95, 1.65, 1.94, 2.53, 2.21, 1.94, 2.05, 2.22, 
3, 3.28, 1.55, 3.85, 2.4, 2.1, 1.98, 1.81, 2.48, 1.66, 2.06, 
1.23, 3.75, 1.99, 1.67, 1.93)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-160L))



library(Rmisc)
library(ggplot2)

tglf2 <- summarySE(iso, measurevar="form", groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"),na.rm=TRUE)

pd <- position_dodge(0.5)

p=ggplot(tglf2, aes(x=P, y=form,colour=cultivar,group=cultivar)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se),colour="black", 
            width=.2,position=pd) +
geom_line(position=pd) +
geom_point(aes(shape=cultivar),size=3.5,position=pd)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(0, 16, 17,1))+
scale_color_manual(values=c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"))+
facet_grid(~Waterlogging)


 ann_text <- data.frame(P = 30,shoot = 3,lab = "Text",
                   Waterlogging = factor(Waterlogged,levels = c("Non-waterlogged","Waterlogged")))
 p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text")
```

[image: plot]

WHen I try to run the ann_text line I get an error message that it cant find the object waterlogging. I am trying to find the solution found here [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround adding some variables to the original data. I just added three columns filled with `NA`, except for the position where you want your text and the text itself (making sure it is located in the facet level where you want your label, *i.e.*, waterlogged).

```
#Adding the three variables to the data
tglf2 <- data.frame(tglf2,
                    P2 = c(rep(NA,(nrow(tglf2)-1)),30),
                    text = c(rep(NA,(nrow(tglf2)-1)),"MyText"),
                    form2 = c(rep(NA,(nrow(tglf2)-1)),3))
```

As the text information is already contained in the data, you just need to add the following code to your plot.

```
geom_text(aes(x = P2, y = form2, label = text),
            col = "black")
```

Here is the final result

[image: plot with text]

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. If I wanted it in the other panel, ie, Non-waterlogged, what would I change?

Comment: You could just change the position of the entries in the three columns I added (`P2`,`form2` and `label`), so that they correspond to a row where its level in the `Waterlogging` column is Non-waterlogged. For example, the first row of `tglf2` is Non-waterlogged, so I can add the entry for plotting the text in that row: `tglf2 <- data.frame(tglf2,
                    P2 = c(30,rep(NA,(nrow(tglf2)-1))),
                    text = c("MyText",rep(NA,(nrow(tglf2)-1))),
                    form2 = c(3,rep(NA,(nrow(tglf2)-1))))`

Comment: THe structure of this code to put the label in the non watrlogged facet is not structured in the required way. Can you please check it?

Comment: I ran it and it constructs the required plot. Just be sure to run first `tglf2 <- summarySE(iso, measurevar="form", groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"),na.rm=TRUE)` and then the code I posted in last comment.