# Adding a shaded area to facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am really new to R and trying to lean it myself but now I got stuck in a place. I have tried to add a shaded area to a facet but it adds a shaded area to every facet. I wanna highlight a time from 2017-08-08 to 2017-08-16 only and I don't know how to do it.

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
ggplot(data = Andmed3, aes(x= Aeg, y = arch, group = Prooviala)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar",fun.data = mean_se, aes(group = Prooviala, color = Prooviala)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="line",lwd=1,aes (group= Prooviala, color = Prooviala)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean, shape = 16, size = 2, aes(color = Prooviala)) + 
  facet_grid(~Periood, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
  labs(x = "Kuupäev", y = "Arhede 16S rRNA geenikoopiate arv")+ 
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = " %e %b %y") + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.POSIXct('2017-08-08', format = '%Y-%m-%d'),xmax = as.POSIXct('2017-08-16', format = '%Y-%m-%d'),ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.2, fill = 'grey')
```

[image]

I need my graph to look like my second picture but just with the highlighted background in the first facet.

[image]

Can someone help me with the code?

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) may help you.  Without access to your input data it's difficult to provide a concrete solution.  For future reference, you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Not sure why `scales="free_x"` is not apparently working for you.  Do you have y value numbers in your dataset for the dates which are appearing blank?  Can you please share your data with us in a reproducible way?  To do that, type `dput(Andmed3)` into the console, then copy and paste the wall of code you'll see into the body of your question, formatted as code.  The code will look something like `structure(...)`.  This way we can reproduce your dataframe and your resulting chart with the code you provided.