# Add a vector of labels to multiple plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, statistics, p-value

I have analyzed continuous variables from a publicly available hepatitis dataset (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Hepatitis). I have a vector of p-values that I want to add as labels to these graphs, for example:

```
p_values <- c(
"Age" = 0.004, 
"Albumin" = 0.001, 
"Alk_phosphate" = 0.0034, 
"Bilirubin" = 0.008, 
"Protime" = 0.001, 
"Sgot" = 0.002)
```

How can I do this using ggplot2 or another package?

[image]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52217208/786542

Comment: you need to create a data.frame with the same column name as your faceting variable, then use geom_text onto that