# Auto-numbering panels in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot using `ggplot::facet_wrap()` and I wonder how to automatically add numbers/letters to the label/title of each panel?

`gridExtra` and `complot` solutions are not what I am looking for. It is more related to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52217208/10264278, especially the alternative using the `stickylabeller` package. This package could be perfect but it seems not maintained anymore (I get `package ‘stickylabeller’ is not available for this version of R` message when loading it, R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)).

Is it possible to acheive something similar to `stickylabeller::label_glue()` with `labeller()` function? Ideally I would like to avoid editting my data prior to the plotting process. Reason for that is I would like to be able to quickly change the labels *e.g.* switch from `(a)`, `(b)` to `1.`, `2.`.

What I get:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ am) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

Here is the expected output (without the `am =`  is fine):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining a look-up of the labels, and then call in the `facet_wrap()` statement as here:

```
library(ggplot2)

levels <- sort(unique(mtcars$am))
labels <- c(glue::glue("({LETTERS[levels+1]}) am = {levels}", collapse = ""))
names(labels) <- levels

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ am, labeller = labeller(am = labels)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

It is also possible to make custom labelling function that can be more flexible although they might produce unexpected outputs in other cases, they seems enough here:

```
letters_lab <- function(x){glue::glue("({letters[factor(x)]}) {x}")}
number_lab <- function(x){glue::glue("({as.integer(factor(x))}) {x}")}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris) +
  facet_grid(.~Species, labeller = labeller(Species = number_lab))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = iris) +
  facet_grid(.~Species, labeller = labeller(Species = letters_lab))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ am, labeller = labeller(am = letters_lab))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but I am looking for something that does not require to create that lookup table. The reason is that, if you change variables used for facetting, you will have to make another lookup table wich is, sometimes very long :p

Comment: However, I guess it is possible to create a function that makes it easier to edit those labels.

Comment: That makes sense. Dynamic table isn't too difficult, but requires a little `glueing`.  I've updated my solution.  The stickylabeller looks goods. I'd not come across it before.

Comment: I was able to make the expected output but changing very little of your code with the `glue::glue()` functions. To make it re-usable across plots, I made more general functions like `letters_lab <- function(x){glue::glue("({letters[factor(x)]}) {x}")}` or `number_lab <- function(x){glue::glue("({as.integer(factor(x))}) {x}")}` and used them like so `facet_grid(.~Species, labeller = labeller(Species = number_lab))`.

Comment: Nice.  I'm always pleased to find better ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

in case you want to use `stickylabeller`, you still can by using the github version.

```
devtools::install_github("rensa/stickylabeller")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ am, labeller = stickylabeller::label_glue('({.n}) am = {am}')) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

Comment: Ooooh what a nice trick! I did not know about this possibility. I'll use this until we find something that does not rely on a (not so) old package :) Many thanks!