# How to fix problem with "for" in the ggplot2 label

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I'm trying to make a plot with facets and add annotations in each of the facets.

I want the annotations to look like "*p* for trend=0.001" like the plot such as  this image.

[image]

The plot I made looks like the following:

[image]

```
ann_text <- data.frame(x = rep(5,6), y = rep(1,6),
                       conf.low = rep(5,6), conf.high = rep(5,6),
                       term = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), 
                       pvalue = c("==0.04", "<0.001", "==0.999", "==0.999", "==0.99", "==0.99"))
ann_text$term <- factor(ann_text$term)


p <- ggplot(ann_text, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  facet_wrap(.~term) +
    geom_text(data = ann_text, 
            aes(label=paste0(rep('italic(p)~fo~trend', 6), pvalue)), 
            parse = TRUE, size = 7)
p
```

I think I'm almost there, but "r" is missing in the annotation, because when I add "r", it raises the following error message.

```
Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : <text>:1:14: unexpected '~'
1: italic(p)~for~
                 ^
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could use something along the lines of code mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes inside the single-quoted expression to specify the character string you do not want interpreted as code. Incidentally, you do not need to use `rep()` because `paste0()` is vectorized and will apply the `'italic(p)~"for trend"'` part to however many `pvalue` elements there are. So, like this:

```
p <- ggplot(ann_text, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  facet_wrap(.~term) +
    geom_text(data = ann_text, 
            aes(label=paste0('italic(p)~"for trend"', pvalue)), 
            parse = TRUE, size = 7)

p
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts:**

I think, that `for` in this case is recognized something like a function, command or operator.

And R waits for something a la: `for == bla-bla, for(bla-bla)` etc...

**How to solve:**

I tried to fix this problem with latin unicode `f o r` characters. But it didn't help.

But we have **Cyrillic Small Letter O**, ha-ha. And it helps! ;)

**Your modified code:**

```
ann_text <- data.frame(x = rep(5,6), y = rep(1,6),
                       conf.low = rep(5,6), conf.high = rep(5,6),
                       term = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), 
                       pvalue = c("==0.04", "<0.001", "==0.999", "==0.999", "==0.99", "==0.99"))
ann_text$term <- factor(ann_text$term)


p <- ggplot(ann_text, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    facet_wrap(.~term) +
    geom_text(data = ann_text, 
              aes(label=paste0(rep('italic(p)~f\U043Er~trend', 6), pvalue)), 
              parse = TRUE, size = 7)
p
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the use of Cyrillic letters.