# Add standard deviation text overlay on ggplot geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

A plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds |> 
  filter(x > 0) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = log(price))) +
  geom_point()
```

Looks like this:
[image]

The standard deviation of log(diamonds$Price) (filtered where x > 0) is 1.014611:

```
diamonds |> 
  filter(x > 0) |> 
  pull(price) |> 
  log() |> 
  sd() # 1.014611
```

I wouldlike to overlay this on top of my plot somewhere and call it just 'sd'. In this case it would say 'sd = 1.014611'. Can I do this?

[EDIT]

Bonus if across facets. Tried:

```
annotations <- diamonds |> 
  filter(x > 0) |> 
  group_by(cut) |> 
  summarise(sd_log_price = paste0("sd = ", round(sd(log(price)), 2)))

diamonds |> 
  filter(x > 0) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = log(price))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(label = annotations$sd_log_price) + # Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (53932): label
  facet_wrap(. ~ cut)
```

But this throws the error in the comment.

Comment: `ggplot2::annotate()` isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of nearly synonymous ways of getting text onto a plot (e.g. `ggplot2::annotate()`, `ggplot2::geom_text()`).

Note here that I used the {magrittr} pipe (`%>%`) instead of the new native pipe (`|>`) to make use of the `.` function of the former in the `paste0()` to create the annotation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

annotation <- diamonds |> 
  filter(x > 0) |> 
  pull(price) |> 
  log() |> 
  sd() |>
  round(6) %>% 
  paste0("sd = ", .)

diamonds |> 
  filter(x > 0) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = log(price))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = annotation, x = -Inf, y = Inf), hjust = -0.5, vjust = 2, size = 6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks this did work. Any idea how to do this across facets? I made an edit

Comment: You feed in a dataframe with the faceting variable and the label for each facet. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Yep, that link got me what I needed, cheers