# Add text annotations at consistent locations in facet_grid when scale = 'free_y' + ggplot2 + r

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, label, facet

I need to annotate a set of chats in a facet grid where the y axis is scale is set to `scale = 'free_y'`.

As the scales are very different, when I set the y position of the geom_text the text location is also very different for each graph. Is there any method to correct for this so that they are all in the same elate x,y position on each chart in the facet grid?

The example below demonstrates the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(name = c('Jim',"Bob", "Sue",'Jim',"Bob", "Sue",'Jim',"Bob", "Sue"), 
                 r = c(1,10,100,2,20,200,3,30,300), z = c(1,10,100,2,20,200,3,30,300))
  
p <- ggplot(df, aes(z, r)) + geom_line()

p <- p + facet_grid(vars(name),scales = "free")

dfl <- data.frame(name = c('Jim',"Bob", "Sue"), r = c(-0.2, 0.5, -0.4))

p + geom_text(data = dfl, aes(200, 10,label = r), check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

Ideally, in this example, the labels would all be the same position as the first chart in the facet gris "Bob".

I have reviewed this previous question, which addresses text annotation on a single chart in a facet grid, but not the placement in the case of different y scales per facet - [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2)

Comment: No, I have updated my question to reflect why. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can control the annotations:

```
p + geom_text(
  size    = 5,
  data    = dat_text,
  mapping = aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label),
  hjust   = 1.05,
  vjust   = 1.5
)

dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c(-0.2, 0.5, -0.4),
  name  = c('Jim', 'Bob', 'Sue')
)
```

[image]