# How can I prevent geom_text from overlapping labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `geom_text` from `ggplot` to annotate each of my plots in a `facet_wrap`. My code is shown below. `num_zeros_text` is just a dataframe with a single column, `label`, with a number in each row. I'm trying to follow the answer posted by Kamil Slowikowski in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) post. For some reason, my labels are ending up "overlapping" each other (see picture below), where essentially all numbers from the dataframe `num_zeros_text` are being displayed on each plot (I believe). I can't figure out why.

```
  ggplot(normalized_counts_subsampled, aes(value)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_wrap(~bins, 100) +
    geom_text(data = num_zeros_text,
              aes(x = 0.75, y=50, label=label))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). What do you have in `num_zeros_test$label`? Is it one label for each graph? Is it a label for some graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you labels dataset does not contain the facetting variable. Hence, how should `ggplot2` know that you want only one number per facet and in which order? As a consequence all numbers are plotted in each facet.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of your issue based on `iris`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

num_zeros_text <- data.frame(
  label = c(1, 2, 3)
)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) +
  geom_text(data = num_zeros_text,
            aes(x = 0.75, y=50, label=label))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

To fix your issue add a second column with the facetting variable to your labels dataset, i.e. for my reprex a `Species` column:

```r
num_zeros_text$Species <- unique(iris$Species)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) +
  geom_text(data = num_zeros_text,
            aes(x = 0.75, y=50, label=label))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]