# Annotate left side of facet_grid using tag_facet_outside?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, facet-grid

Am following a very similar query to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889625/annotating-text-on-individual-facet-in-ggplot2) and answer from @Tung, where I'd like to annotate a facet_grid using letters on the outside of the plot. The wonderful `egg::tag_facet_outside` function is kind of what I'm after...

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cyl ~ am, switch = 'y') +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside')

library(egg)
tag_facet_outside(p)
```

Which yields this...

[image]

My question is whether I can shift the roman numeral labels that are currently on the **right** hand side of the graph to the **left** hand side? Within tag_facet_outside() there is the option to specify parameters for `tag_fun_right=` as well as options of specifying coordinates but I just can't seem to get these labels to appear all the way over to the left.

Next one is - is it possible to remove the top row of tags altogether, possibly by specifying the `tag_fun_top` ?
Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to stick with `ggplot2` and use a custom `labeller` function and `theme` options. Basically, as far as I get it `egg::tag_facet_outside` is doing more or less the same under the hood.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl ~ am,
    switch = "y",
    labeller = labeller(
      am = ~ paste0("(", letters[as.numeric(factor(.x))], ")"),
      cyl = ~ paste0(as.roman(as.numeric(factor(.x))), ".")
    )
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0, size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(vjust = 1, angle = 0, size = rel(1), face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5.5))
  )
```

[image]

To get rid off the  top row of labels you could use
`theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())`:

```r
last_plot() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

**UPDATE** Adding the annotations while still keeping the strip labels could be achieved via `ggh4x::facet_grid2` like so. Basically I use a helper column  `cyl2` to add two layers of  `cyl` facets where one is used for the annotations, while the second is used for the default strip labels. Via the `strip` argument `ggh4x::facet_grid2` allows to style  the two layers separately:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

mtcars$cyl2 <- mtcars$cyl

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_nested(cyl + cyl2 ~ am,
             switch = "y",
             labeller = labeller(
               am = ~ paste0("(", letters[as.numeric(factor(.x))], ")"),
               cyl = ~ paste0(as.roman(as.numeric(factor(.x))), ".")
             ),
             strip = strip_themed(background_y = list(
               element_blank(),
               element_rect(fill = "grey85")
             ),
             text_y = list(
               element_text(vjust = 1, angle = 0, size = rel(1), face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5.5)),
               element_text(vjust = .5, angle = 90, size = rel(1), margin = margin(4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4))
             ),
             by_layer_y = TRUE
             )
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0, size = rel(1), face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you greatly, really appreciate it. How would you go about adding those annotations whilst also retaining the horizontal strip chart labels, say to also indicate cyl for each row in the above example?

Comment: Hi Timmo83. I just added an update to show one approach to add the annotations while retaining the default strip labels.

Comment: Ah of course! The ggh4x package is awesome but I didn't realize that function - even better. Thanks again!