Adding annotate text and arrow to one facet of histogram plot in ggplot
Using a similar general approach in a previous question (Y axis to show counts with geom_density and geom_histogram combined in ggplot) to building a faceted histogram plot, I am trying to add some text that aligns just to the right of the centered line at xintercept=50, with an arrow pointing to the right.
The current code I have below uses annotate() in a way that mostly satisfactorily accomplishes this, but with one big caveat--I would ideally want to have the text and arrow only show up in one facet (the top left facet, if able to choose).
From my research thus far, it's not clear to me that this is accomplishable with annotate(), but I thought I'd see if anyone has ideas. There are a couple of answers on this question (Annotating text on individual facet in ggplot2), though they are a decade old and use geom_text() instead. Can this be done with annotate() in my current code structure?

Code to make the figure:
ggplot(d, aes(x = hours)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density * nrow(d))), 
                 binwidth = 10, alpha = 0.3, color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~condition) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 90, by = 10),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50, color = "red", linetype = "solid", size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  annotate("text", x = 50, y = 2.2, hjust = -0.05, vjust = 1, 
           label= "More this way",
           size = 2.8, fontface = "bold") +
  annotate("segment", x = 52, y = 2, xend = 80, size = 1,
         arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(0.05, "npc"))) +
  labs(title = "Hours", x = "Allotment", y = NULL) +
  theme_bw()

Toy data:
d<-structure(list(hours = c(70, 10, 20, 10, 50, 10, 
50, 60, 50, 70, 40, 90, 40, 60, 70, 40, 50, 60, 80, 10, 90, 50, 
40, 40, 70, 50, 40, 10, 80, 70, 70, 90, 20, 10, 60, 90, 10, 20, 
90, 70, 30, 60, 90, 60, 90, 20, 20, 20, 10, 40), money = c(60, 
70, 10, 10, 40, 30, 40, 40, 50, 80, 90, 70, 50, 60, 80, 20, 10, 
90, 20, 40, 90, 40, 30, 60, 40, 60, 70, 90, 10, 20, 80, 90, 80, 
60, 70, 70, 60, 50, 60, 90, 90, 80, 60, 40, 30, 80, 30, 20, 60, 
20), condition = structure(c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), levels = c("condition_control", 
"conditionA", "conditionB", "conditionC", "conditionD"
), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    condition = structure(2:5, levels = c("condition_control", 
    "conditionA", "conditionB", "conditionC", "conditionD"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(6L, 9L, 17L, 
    21L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 33L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 42L, 48L), c(10L, 
    12L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 28L, 31L, 40L, 43L, 49L), c(1L, 
    7L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 25L, 26L, 34L, 47L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    11L, 13L, 16L, 30L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 50L
    )), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), .drop = TRUE))


It is already answered on the post you linked to (see the recommended answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47836541 You need to use geom_segment and geom_text.

No, this feature has been requested but is not part of the project plan.

Your example data looks like you pasted it in twice, so it doesn't run as provided.

You can add a text annotation to one facet by providing a local data frame for a layer of geom_text:   geom_text(data = data.frame(hours = 50, condition = "conditionA"), y = 2.2, hjust = -0.05, vjust = 1, label= "More this way", size = 2.8, fontface = "bold") + ...
